# Shortcut to clear swap on demand

Tags: memory, xfce, swap, cache

I am trying to make a shortcut on my desktop where i can just click on it from the Quicklauncher panel when the system is slowing down to clear the swap. 
[image: Quicklauncher from the panel bar]

Right now i am using this code in terminal:

```
sudo swapoff -a && swapon -a
```

but i don't know if a sudo command will work from a shortcut.

Comment: what is the correct command to put on my shortcut ?

Comment: why don't you try the comand that you posted?

Comment: so you say what i did is actually good ?

Comment: Is the swap actually the cause of the system "slowing down"? In that case, there is likely some memory-hungry processes running. If there are memory-hungry processes running, they would likely _need_ swap. What I'm saying is that toggling swap off and on again may fail if you have a real low memory situation. It would probably be better to investigate _why_ the system is running slowly (i.e. what processes are hogging the memory).

Comment: I don`t see how "clearing the swap" would speed up your system. This should make things even slower as your system starts to swap out from RAM again.

Comment: Its a laptop 4GB with 8GB swap partition XFCE Mint 19.2. The hungry hippo is Firefox..

Comment: After reading and deeper searching, i installed  Reduce RAM Usage Plugin for Firefox and changed some settings in about:config. Now i can open about 20+ tabs (specially TubeYou) and browse one after the other without any slow down. The background tabs gets put on hold until i get to it. Also i deleted the swap partition, i find it useless and frustrating for my machine.